# Metodo vue js get retorna valor Undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Estoy llamando un metodo axios con vuejs

```
isRegistrado: function(){
            i_dni = this.inscription.num_dni;
            i_curso = this.inscription.specialization_course;
            console.log(i_dni + " curso:"+i_curso+ "");
            axios.get('/inscripcion-existe/'+i_dni+'@'+i_curso).then(response => {
                console.log("Func:"+response.data)
                return response.data;
            }).catch(error => {
                this.loading = false
                this.errors = error
                analysisErrorGet(error)
                return 7
            })            
        },
```

luego desde otra función de javascript llamo la anterior

```
retorno_verificacion = this.isRegistrado()
console.log("retorno: "+retorno_verificacion)
if (retorno_verificacion == 0){                                                                        
          console.log("Desde A"+retorno_verificacion);                                                                        
return 1}
```

La función get retorna lo que deseo, la validación correcta, pero al llamarla desde otra función primero me muestra en consola:

```
12312341 curso:1
retorno: undefined
Func:1
```

el valor que debería darme es 1, pero me muestra undefined y luego recién sale el 1, entonces en la función donde necesito la validación me muestra undefined y no puedo recuperar correctamente los datos.

Comment: que pasa si cambias ``retorno_verificacion = this.isRegistrado()`` por ``retorno_verificacion = async() => await this.isRegistrado()``?

Comment: retorno: async() => await this.isRegistrado()   <- eso me aparece en el log ahora

Comment: porque era una constante y ahora es una funcion, donde lo llamas como ``retorno_verificacion`` tenes que poner ``retorno_verificacion()``

Comment: entonces debería crear una función así? y de hacerlo en que constante puedo almacenar el resultado o como debería hacerlo por favor

Comment: vos ya tenes una funcion que se encarga de traer datos, ``isRegistrado `` y vos decis en la pregunta que anda bien. Lo que sospecho que te esta pasando es que cuando haces la asignacion ``retorno_verificacion = this.isRegistrado()``, al no haber un ``await`` no espera que se resuelva la funcion ``isRegistrado`` y por eso te trae undefined. No veo en que momento declaras ``retorno_verificacion``, solo veo cuando la asignas

Answer (score 0):

Sospecho que el problema es de sincronia,

```
retorno_verificacion = this.isRegistrado()
```

Esto intenta guardar el resultado de la funcion `isRegistrado` pero al no tener un `await` pasa a la siguiente linea sin resolver nada

Yo probaria asi:

```
const resultadoAsync = async() => this.isRegistrado()

console.log("retorno: "+resultadoAsync)
if (resultadoAsync == 0){                                                                        
   console.log("Desde A"+resultadoAsync);                                                                        
   return 1
}
```